# How to (force Yocto to) create ${PN}.deb file?

Tags: yocto

I'm trying to add a library (a cmake project) to my Yocto project/image.

The package essentially consists of one static library (named hello.a) with some header files in C.

I wrote a recipe and could configure, compile, package it.

The packaging results are four files {hello-dbg, hello-dev, hello-src, hello-staticdev}.deb

So there is no hello.deb.

**And that seems to be a problem preventing me to create image.**

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 packagegroup-utils-extra : Depends: hello but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to add that by defining:

```
FILES_${PN} += "/usr/lib/hello.a"
```

bitbake does not allow adding static libraries to anything but `staticdev` -> so that does not work.

**My question is then, as the title says, how to (force Yocto to) create ${PN}.deb file?**

Answer (score 1):

The empty packages (i.e. containing no files) are not created by default. If you want to override it, you can do it via the `ALLOW_EMPTY` variable for a package like this:

```
ALLOW_EMPTY:${PN} = "1"
```

You can also check the [official documentation for `ALLOW_EMPTY`](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html?highlight=allow_empty#term-ALLOW_EMPTY).

Just for clarification:

- You can install the `${PN}` package (it won't install any file on the target system).
- As before, your static library will still be shipped in the `${PN}-staticdev` package.